# How to use the Oracle partition table in ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: oracle, arcgis

ArcGIS is connected to Oracle directly(no ArcSDE).

Oracle create a partition table,ArcCatalog can't show this table,others can.

I know,Processing by means of ArcSDE,but I don't know this way.

I can only speak a little English,thanks！

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you please elaborate your question having your effort like code or something so that people could get your problem early and help you? Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I can only speak a little English.Can you help me to send the issue to other platforms?thank you!!!                                        ArcGIS is connected to Oracle directly(no ArcSDE).                                        Oracle create a partition table,ArcCatalog can't show this table,others can.